# Trying to get to next row in excel

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to go to the next row when I retrieve a printer name. I am currently building a list of all available printers that I can print from, but they all keep writing over to the same cell.

I have tried making increments such as row = row + 1, but with no success

```
   Dim PlotRow As Integer


  Set Layout = NewFile.ModelSpace.Layout      'Setting the layout to ModelSpace viewport
  Layout.RefreshPlotDeviceInfo                'Refresh the current plot information 
  plotDevices = Layout.GetPlotDeviceNames()   'Setting the plotting view for this current layout

  PlotRow = 18
  Dim x As Integer
  For x = LBound(plotDevices) To UBound(plotDevices)

      Cells(PlotRow, 10) = plotDevices(x)
      Debug.Print plotDevices(x)
      PlotRow = PlotRow + 1

  Next
```

I want to build a list of all valid printers, without over writing each cell.

Comment: Are you sure there's more than one printer? Add the `PlotRow` variable to your `Debug.Print` just to see what's there.

Comment: Yep,  shows more printers, but it's not incrementing

Comment: Please Autocad tag.  Without Autocad on my computer, I cannot replicate the problem, cannot execute  Set Layout = NewFile.ModelSpace.Layout

Comment: from your [next question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58368760/trying-to-build-a-data-validation-list-with-array-that-keeps-building) I'd argue this one is solved: if so, please add a comment to let people know how you solved it. Otherwise, keep giving feedback to pepole trying at helping you

Comment: Honestly.. I didn't changed anything here. All I did was save the file, and reopened it. The code only runs once, but will have the same problem if you run it twice.