# Trying to build a data validation list with array that keeps building

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to build a data validation list that adds values to the list which is fed from a for loop. Right now, I have the for loop that generates values and then write them into a column.

What I am trying to accomplish is instead of writing them to a cell, I would like to write them directly to the data validation list. (So the program runs faster)

The "For Loop" is as shown:

```
Dim PlotRow As Integer


  Set Layout = NewFile.ModelSpace.Layout      'Setting the layout to ModelSpace viewport
  Layout.RefreshPlotDeviceInfo                'Refresh the current plot information 
  plotDevices = Layout.GetPlotDeviceNames()   'Setting the plotting view for this current layout

  PlotRow = 18
  Dim x As Integer
  For x = LBound(plotDevices) To UBound(plotDevices)

      Cells(PlotRow, 10) = plotDevices(x)
      Debug.Print plotDevices(x)
      PlotRow = PlotRow + 1

  Next
```

I have tried modifying the data validation code written by Davy C. But with no success.

His link can be seen here: [How to pass values from an array to a drop down list in a certain cell (not combo list) in excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36208342/how-to-pass-values-from-an-array-to-a-drop-down-list-in-a-certain-cell-not-comb)

The raw data validation code can be shown here:

```
Dim myArray
myArray = Array("1", "2", "3")

Range("A" & 1).Select

With Selection.Validation
    .Delete
    .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Operator:= _
    xlBetween, Formula1:=myArray(0) & "," & myArray(1) & "," & myArray(2)
    .IgnoreBlank = True
    .InCellDropdown = True
    .InputTitle = ""
    .ErrorTitle = ""
    .InputMessage = ""
    .ErrorMessage = ""
    .ShowInput = True
    .ShowError = True
End With
```

I have the for loop running, and I have a good setup on how to write the data validation code. Instead of `Cells(PlotRow, 10)` I would like to put a data validation box for that cell in that column.

Comment: Would `Formula1:=Join(plotDevices, ",")` do it foryou?

Comment: you'd better give proper feedback to [your previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58365980/trying-to-get-to-next-row-in-excel) before opening a new (?) one

Comment: @chrisneilsen That will do it!